# doubts regarding the output of canny and findcountours in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I am using the standard flow to process an image and just find I cannot understand the meaning of contours generated by canny and  findCountours.
Here is the image:
[image]

And after canny:

[image]

after findContours, it has 4 contours. So I draw the 4 contours out.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

That is the confusing part: why does it have 4 contours instead of 2? Because from the canny output, we can only see 2 contours: the outside one and the inside one.

Could someone clear my doubts?

Thanks
Deryk

code is here:

```
Mat src = imread("images/andgate.png");
Mat gray;
cvtColor(src, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
Mat bw;
Canny(gray, bw, 100, 200);
vector<vector<Point> > contours2;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy2;

findContours(bw, contours2, hierarchy2,CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

Comment: `Canny` will create two contours: one for the outside of the edge, and  one for the inside.

Comment: Then in such a case, there are no benefits using canny. We can just use threshold. Is it right?
Then my question is when to use canny and when to use threshold?

Comment: In this case, yes. Since your original image is binary, you can dispense with `Canny` and just call `findContours()` directly.